# Celery jobs not running

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

When I run m script like this on ubuntu as root, it works:

```
./my_celery.sh
```

But when it runs with Upstart like this it does not execute the task:

Upstart:

```
description "Django instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
exec /var/www/webapps/myapp/my_celery.sh
```

Start it:

service my_celery start

Log:

```
[2015-07-20 11:56:46,563: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task The Parmalat Daily Report (minamobime_coza.tasks.parmalat_report)
```

The tasks are never executed

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting upstart to run celery workers - in fact upstart never quite managed to live up to its promise.

I would recommend using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) instead of upstart to manage the celery workers - example config file:

`/etc/supervisor.d/celery.conf`

```
[program:celery]
command=celery worker --app=path.to.my.tasks    
user=celery
autostart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=250MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
redirect_stderr=true
```